# Visual studio not showing android device to debug (Xamarin)

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, adb

I'm a Xamarin developer and i have an android phone (Mi Mix 2), visual studio 2017 (15.7.6). Last month, everything is working great, i've using adb over wifi and can debug application from visual studio on my phone.

The problem happen after i'm upgrade android version to MIUI 10 - Adnroid 8.0.0 - EU version (to test face id). Still can connect to my phone, access my files over MTP and adb devices showing my phone... but visual studio does not show it and cannot debug.

adb issue - see picture:

[image]

I've tried:
 - Other computer, other windows
 - Using usb cables.
 - Other wifi, hotspot.
 - Reinstall drivers.
 - And most of things that i found in google...

In my mac book, it still working fine, just visual studio for windows not detect my phone.

My first thing is may be new android version have issue, but on my macbook still work fine, adb devices (windows) still showing my phone.

Comment: update to VS2017 15.8.7 and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-flash SupperSU 2.82 SR3. Now it's working fine, both usb and wifi, don't know why =]]

https://download.chainfire.eu/1122/SuperSU/SR3-SuperSU-v2.82-SR3-20170813133244.zip?retrieve_file=1